# Why are superclasses called superclass and not baseclass or primary class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I does not make much sense to me.

When you extend a class, you basically create a new object which adds features to an existing object.

But when I think of the word "superclass", I think of something big, that can host everything that is beneath it. Which is not the case, since you cannot call anything of a subclass from a superclass.

On the contrary, since a subclass inherits all public methods of its superclasses, the subclasses are definitely "bigger".

So I think superclasses should be called baseclasses or rootclasses or something similar. 
And subclasses should be the superclasses.

Could somebody helpe me understand all this better?

Anyway, I should go back to my code =)

Comment: The words used is subjective. Java programmers call it "super" and "sub". C++ programmers call it "base" and "derived". Similarly, Java programmers call class/instance functions "methods" and C++ programmers call it "members". Some people mix match. You may have programmers that use other languages calling it "base". Personally I still call it "base" class and "derived" class. So it's entirely up to that individual. Your question is thus opinion based or just not fit for "stack overflow".

Comment: Class hierarchies are typically illustrated top-to-bottom, in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for example.

Comment: It is useless to argue about terminology.  Just accept it and go ahead.

Comment: Why is the word 'blue', 'blue' I want to call it klapen. See, when I think of klapen I imagine the sky and the ocean.

Comment: Just to chime in here: Every class you define has a superclass. If you do not specify the superclass with an extends clause, the superclass is the class java.lang.Object.

Comment: I heard that superclass is used similarly to superego (in psychoanalysis). However I cannot still find an evidence that it is true. If it is true, then this will not be opinion-based, because it would have a specific reason why it was chosen to be like that. If anyone finds a good source for this, I would be glad to read it.

Answer (score 3):

It might be caused by the visual representation of a class hierarchy in (UML) [class diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram), where the base classes / **super**classes are positioned over ("**super**" means "**over**") the extending classes / **sub**classes ("**sub**" means "**under**").

[image]